# RegEdit on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, browser

HK_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE in regedit will always have path of IE when it is not am default browser.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as intended. `App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE` is not where the default browser is set. `App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE` is where the path to iexplore.exe is stored. So naturally it will always have the path to Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong registry key. The information is not stored there, but under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` under Windows XP.